# Longpolling : Sending extra variable

Tags: php, jquery, long-polling

I am doing a simple longpolling using jquery and php.. It's going on great.. but when I am sending and extra variable.. then the longpolling is not showing the current value that it's supposed to show... My code is below..

The one which is working :

```
    function getContent(time)
{

    var queryString = {'time': time};

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: queryString,
            success: function(data){

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                $('#response').html(obj.data_from_file);
                getContent(obj.time);
            },

            error : function(){
            getContent(time);
            }
        }
    );
}


$(document).ready(function(){

  getContent();
});
```

The one which is working on page refresh.. but longpolling is not happening...

```
function getContent(time)
{
    var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';      
    var queryString = {'time': time, 'name':name};

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: queryString,
            success: function(data){

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                $('#response').html(obj.data_from_file);
                getContent(obj.time);
            },

            error : function(){
            getContent(time);
            }
        }
    );
}


$(document).ready(function(){

  getContent();
});
```

PHP side...

```
while (true) {
    $last_ajax_call = isset($_GET['time']) ? (int)$_GET['time'] : null;
    $name = $_GET['name'];

               //rest of the code...............
            }
else{
sleep(1);
continue;
}
```

Comment: It is probably a cache issue, try `cache : false` in your ajax calls.

Comment: nah... it didnot work

Comment: Perhaps not, but totally sure the cache addition was actually loaded? The script is also cached, so to be sure, add ?xyz=123 or something like that after the script declaration. An extra variable sent clientside cannot halt a serverside script from working, unless it is processed and the serverside script fails, or if the serverside script tries to process it, but it is never sent.